# Change datasource properties name Jooq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jooq

I have a spring boot application configured with jooq. My application.properties have below db configuration :

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb 
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres@123
```

It auto-configure a DataSource and everything is working fine. What if I want to change the property names to below:

```
datasource.postgresql.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springbootdb
datasource.postgresql.username=postgres
datasource.postgresql.password=postgres@123
```

Where I have to further make configuration changes with new name for properties. Any help?

Comment: What is embedded on using a postgres database?

Comment: Jooq library auto create the DSLContext(driver to connect to db) using spring.datasource.url etc properties.

Comment: Changing the property names will not let Spring Boot use those to configure a datasource and you will end up with no datasource. Unless you configure one yourself. But why make it more complex then needed? Also there is no embedded database driver maybe you want to read up on what an embedded database is.